# Create a hit counter in PHP with help of database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have webpages with URL http://siteurl/directory/onemore/$fileID.php 
I am trying to extract just the $fileID and after that use

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID = $fileID");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$hits = $rows['HITS'];
$hits = $hits + 1;
$query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tablename SET HITS = $hits WHERE ID = $fileID");
echo 'Total hits on page'.$hits.'';
```

I can't figure out how to get just the $fileID part and wanted to ask is the rest of my procedure correct?

**EDIT**

With the code above hits get stuck at one. I was thinking that after each page refresh they will update to +1.

Comment: small tip: you can add 1 to the value like this too in database $mysqli->query("UPDATE tablename SET HITS = HITS + 1");

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I extract just $fileID

Comment: @Asain: if TheNAkos intended to answer the questoin I'm sure he/she would have posted an answer not a comment. But the comment was a little terse. Certainly "...hits=hits+1.." is a lot safer in that it avoids innaccuracies due to timing isues / conscurrency. But the update stateemnt should have a WHERE clause to specify the row to be updated. If the only reason you are doing the SELECT is to find the existing value of $row['HITS'] then it is reduntant. There are several other bad practices in the code here.

Comment: Sidenote: You will want to use a `WHERE` clause. Doing it this way will update all your rows.

Comment: Thank you.It has actually updated all the hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the $fileId like this:

```
/* $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] results to e.g. '/directory/onemore/5.php' */
/* basename(...) results to e.g. '5.php' */
$fileName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
/* take the text before the last occurrence of '.' */
$fileID = substr($fileName, 0, strrpos($fileName, '.'));


$query = $mysqli->query("UPDATE tablename SET HITS = HITS + 1 WHERE ID = $fileID");

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID = $fileID");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$hits = $rows['HITS'];
echo 'Total hits on page'.$hits.'';
```

Comment: I tried this code and after that put my MySQL code written above. It has set every HIT value in database to 1 and after that stopped updating them.

Comment: I oversaw an error in your sql statement, and updated my answer above

Comment: There is still one problem, the echo statement now shows `Total hits on page` and nothing after that.

Comment: I checked my database and the hits are not incrementing they are set on 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

> Output

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to print the hits every time, you can increment it in a single query which is a bit more clear and efficient.

```
UPDATE tablename SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = $fileID
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting $fileID of the URL:
Have a look at [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.pathinfo.php) - this function extracts the URL in different parts

In your case it would be:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$fileID = $path_parts['filename'];
```

Your update query will work, in case you only want to count without showing the new value,  you could make it more simple - just increment HITS while updating the table row:

```
$query = mysqli->query("UPDATE tablename SET HITS = HITS+1 WHERE ID = $fileID");
```